# How to make EditText not change it's size automatically

Tags: android, size, android-edittext

Here I have `EditText` and `ImageButton`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:layout_weight=".86"
        android:textStyle="italic|normal"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/search_button_selector"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything seems to be OK, unless I start typing text in `EditText`.

At the beginning it looks like this:

[image]

And after typing text, my `ImageButton` gets smaller:

[image]

How to make `EditText` stand still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe changing the EditText's layout_width to `android:layout_width="0dp"` will fix it.  This will allow the LinearLayout to control the width to fill the space dictated by your weights.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `RelativeLayout` and get rid of those `weight` settings. Just align to image to the right and align the EditText to the left and 'leftOf' the image view:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/searchButton"
    android:textStyle="italic|normal"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/search_button_selector"/>
```

Also you should set the image of your `ImageButton` using `android:src`, not `android:background`. Set the background to transparent color to get rid of the default button background.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="italic|normal"
        android:typeface="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]